# ¿Por qué no puedo ejecutar un controlador mediante código AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mvc

Tengo el siguiente formulario en un modal:

```
<!-- Falta -->
<div class="modal fade" id="faltaModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">

    <form role="form" method="post" id="formFalta">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title"><b>FALTA</b></h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fecha" id="modalFecha" readonly>
              <input class="form-control" type="number" name="no_empleado" id="no_empleado1" readonly>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary back-to-first-modal">REGRESAR</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">GUARDAR</button>
        </div>

      </div>
      
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tengo este código JavaScript:

```
$('#formFalta').submit(function(event) 
{
  event.preventDefault(); // Evita el envío normal del formulario
  
  //var formData = $(this).serialize(); // Serializa los datos del formulario

  // Obtén los valores del formulario
  var fecha1 = $('#modalFecha').val(); 
  var no_empleado1 = $('#no_empleado1').val(); 
  
  $.ajax(
  {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'controladores/faltas.controlador.php',
    data: 
    {
      accion: 'crear',
      fecha: fecha1, 
      no_empleado: no_empleado1
    },
    success: function(response) 
    {
      alert(response); // Muestra la respuesta del servidor (éxito o error)
      $('#faltaModal').modal('hide'); // Cierra el modal de faltas

      calendar.addEvent(
      {
        title: 'FALTA',
        start: selectedDate, // Usa la fecha seleccionada
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderColor: 'red',
        color: 'white'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Y este es mi archivo "faltas.controlador.php":

```
<?php

class ControladorFaltas
{
require_once "conn.php";

    static public function manejarSolicitud()
    {
        $respuesta = array();

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
        {
            if (isset($_POST["accion"]) && $_POST["accion"] == "crear") 
            {
                // Acción 'crear' detectada, llama a la función ctrCrear
                $respuesta = self::ctrCrear();
            }
            else 
            {
                $respuesta["error"] = "Acción no válida.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $respuesta["error"] = "Solicitud no válida.";
        }

        echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }

    static public function ctrCrear()
    {
        $respuesta = array();

        if (isset($_POST["fecha"]) && isset($_POST["no_empleado"])) 
        {
            $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
            $no_empleado = $_POST["no_empleado"];
            $registro = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $num = 1;

            // Realiza la conexión a la base de datos
            $conexion = conn::conn();

            // Prepara la consulta SQL para insertar en la tabla "faltas"
            $sql = "INSERT INTO faltas (inicial, no_empleado, registro, captura) VALUES ('$fecha', '$no_empleado','$registro', '$num')";

            // Ejecuta la consulta
            if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE) 
            {
                // Obtiene el ID generado automáticamente para la última inserción en "faltas"
                $id_movimiento = $conexion->insert_id;

                // Prepara la consulta SQL para insertar en la tabla "events"
                $sql_events = "INSERT INTO events (id_movimiento, no_empleado, start_event, title) VALUES ('$id_movimiento', '$no_empleado', '$fecha', 'FALTA')";

                // Ejecuta la consulta para insertar en "events"
                if ($conexion->query($sql_events) === TRUE) 
                {
                    $respuesta["mensaje"] = "Registro de falta insertado correctamente en ambas tablas (faltas y events)";
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $respuesta["error"] = "Error al insertar el registro en la tabla 'events': " . $conexion->error;
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                $respuesta["error"] = "Error al insertar el registro en la tabla 'faltas': " . $conexion->error;
            }

            // Cierra la conexión a la base de datos
            $conexion->close();
        }

        echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }
}

// Llama a la función manejarSolicitud para procesar la solicitud
ControladorFaltas::manejarSolicitud();

?>
```

De esta manera todo funciona correctamente. La inserción en la base de datos se ejecuta sin problema. El problema surge cuando quiero darle al código un enfoque más orientado al patrón MVC. Mi archivo "faltas.controlador.php" se vería así:

```
<?php

require_once 'modelos/faltas.modelo.php';

class ControladorFaltas
{
    static public function manejarSolicitud()
    {
        $respuesta = array();

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
        {
            if (isset($_POST["accion"]) && $_POST["accion"] == "crear") 
            {
                // Acción 'crear' detectada, llama a la función ctrCrear
                $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
                $no_empleado = $_POST["no_empleado"];
                $respuesta = ModeloFaltas::crearFalta($fecha, $no_empleado);
            }
            else 
            {
                $respuesta["error"] = "Acción no válida.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $respuesta["error"] = "Solicitud no válida.";
        }

        echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }
}

ControladorFaltas::manejarSolicitud();

?>
```

Y mi archivo "faltas.modelo.php" se vería así:

```
require_once "conn.php";
<?php

class ModeloFaltas
{
    public static function crearFalta($fecha, $no_empleado)
    {
        $respuesta = array();

        $registro = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $num = 1;

        // Realizar la conexión a la base de datos
        $conexion = conn::conn();
        // Preparar la consulta SQL para insertar en la tabla "faltas"
        $sql = "INSERT INTO faltas (inicial, no_empleado, registro, captura) VALUES ('$fecha', '$no_empleado','$registro', '$num')";

        // Ejecutar la consulta
        if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE) 
        {
            // Obtener el ID generado automáticamente para la última inserción en "faltas"
            $id_movimiento = $conexion->insert_id;

            // Preparar la consulta SQL para insertar en la tabla "events"
            $sql_events = "INSERT INTO events (id_movimiento, no_empleado, start_event, title) VALUES ('$id_movimiento', '$no_empleado', '$fecha', 'FALTA')";

            // Ejecutar la consulta para insertar en "events"
            if ($conexion->query($sql_events) === TRUE) 
            {
                $respuesta["mensaje"] = "Registro de falta insertado correctamente en ambas tablas (faltas y events)";
            } 
            else 
            {
                $respuesta["error"] = "Error al insertar el registro en la tabla 'events': " . $conexion->error;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            $respuesta["error"] = "Error al insertar el registro en la tabla 'faltas': " . $conexion->error;
        }

        // Cerrar la conexión a la base de datos
        $conexion->close();
        
        return $respuesta;
    }
}

?>
```

Al intentar con el enfoque MVC, no funciona. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Recibo este error: "500 (Error interno del servidor)". El error es relacionado al archivo jquery.min.js en la línea que contiene lo siguiente: "r.send(i.hasContent && i.data || null)".

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías revisar el mensaje completo del error, incluyendo el nombre del archivo y la línea donde ocurre? Un error 500 puede ocurrir hasta por un punto y coma que hayas omitido o cualquier otra tontería o por motivos más serios. Si aún revisando el mensaje no puedes resolver el problema, agrega a la pregunta la traza completa del error, sin importar que sea mucho texto con cosas difíciles de enteder. Eso es oro molido a la hora de corregir código.

Comment: @A.Cedano el error es relacionado al archivo jquery.min.js en la línea que contiene lo siguiente: "r.send(i.hasContent && i.data || null)". Por lo menos eso es lo que me aparece al inspeccionar

Comment: Ya, pero los errores 500 son de servidor, significa que hay error en uno o varios de tus archivos `.php`. Los archivos `.js` están del lado del cliente. Es cierto que en la consola del navegador puedes ver que ocurrió un error 500, pero para analizar a profundidad el error debes revisar el log de errores en tu entorno PHP. Si no sabes cómo hacerlo, investiga. Te aseguro que te ahorrará muchísimo tiempo a la hora de depurar tu código.

Comment: No sé si nos estás tomando el pelo, pero por si acaso,  la consola del browser menciona en su traza `jquery.min.js` porque aguas arriba es el que gatilla la petición Ajax. El error real tienes que verlo en los logs del servidor o por lo menos en la estañaña "network" de chrome devtools, aunque ahí será solo texto